# Trying to calculate the following derivative

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $E$ be a Banach space (or a smooth manifold), $U \subset E$ an open subset and $f : U \to E$ a $C^k$ map, $k \ge 1$. Let $p, q \in E$ and define $\varphi(t) = p + t(q - p)$, where $0 \le t \le 1$.

I don't know how to calculate the derivative $\frac{d}{d t} (f \circ \varphi(t))$. Can someone explain me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $E$ is Banach since $\varphi(t)=p+t(q-p)$ must have a sence, in this case $(f\circ \varphi)'(t)=f'(\varphi(t))\circ \varphi'(t)=f'(p+t(q-p))(q-p)$.